# mobile python 2.6 distribution/development environment?

Tags: python

I'm in an interesting situation. My current computer is going to go in for repairs, and in the meantime I want to get some work done on a friend's computer, but I can't and really don't want to have to set up my development environment on the new PC. Is there a way I can carry around a working Python development environment on a Flash drive? At the very least I'm going to need the Python 2.6 Interpreter + all the libraries I've got installed, and some form of source control (preferably Mercurial).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the whole installed Python directory, eg C:\Python26 of your old PC into your flash drive.

Comment: You also need to deal with registry keys and the like. Not pretty.

Comment: can you name some of those keys that would not work if its not there?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but it needs keys to find things such as the stdlib packages.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set up a remote server on Slicehost or Rackspace cloud and SSH in from your friend's machine. You'll have full control over what libraries you want installed.